Add new directory - Set AccessRules (Permissions)
I'm struggling with creating a new directory and setting the access rules (permissions).  This is my code to create a new directory and add the current user to the permissions.
public static Result CreateDirectory(string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            directoryInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            DirectorySecurity sec = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
            sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(sec);
        }
        return new Result();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new Result(exception: ex, sendMail: true);
    }
}

This works - no error is being thrown and the user is being added to the permission list, but the permissions are not set correctly.

As you can see in the code above, I'm using FileSystemRights.FullControl and AccessControlType.Allow. Why are the permission details empty?

In the FileSystemAccessRule constructor you have options to override inheritance among other. If you look at Advanded (in your screenshot) do you perhaps inherit access rules from the parent folder (and therefor deny any newly set rules)?

Thanks for the hint, but actually no different result even if I set InheritanceFlags and PropagationFlags
